# How do I dynamically create hyperlink line by line(c# asp.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I create hyperlink in placeholder, but when links are created there are adjacent.

I want to create link on the next line but I don't know how to make it.

Comment: Either add a <br> at the end of you link or place the links in table rows. This is pure HTML knowledge...

Comment: Cant you use `<ul>  <li></li>  </ul>`?

Comment: Nice @Mr_Green, forgot about that one...

Answer (score 2):

I counteract this by adding a Literal control the has a line break in it. i.e `<br/>` so it would look something like this.

```
Literal lit = new Literal();

lit.Text = "<br/>";
```

and then add this control after each hyperlink.

Comment: I made it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTML Unordered Lists or HTML Ordered Lists along with suitable CSS Class based on your requirement.

Even a `<p></p>` tag will work.

Eg.:

```
<p><a href="https://www.google.co.in/">Google IN</a></p>
<p><a href="https://www.google.com/">Google1</a></
```

p>

Check this:

[HTML Lists](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp)

HTML Unordered Lists:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="https://www.google.co.in/">Google IN</a></li>
<li><a href="https://www.google.com/">Google1</a></li>
</ul>
```

HTML Ordered Lists:

```
<ol>
 <li><a href="https://www.google.co.in/">Google IN</a></li>
 <li><a href="https://www.google.com/">Google</a></li>
</ol>
```